# R - gsub output undesired space after each char

Tags: r, gsub

I have seen a similar question on stackoverflow before but cannot find it again.
I would like to remove a kind of "_" for each row of a dataframe. But I get the undesired output below.

It works for characters though

```
s="PUERTO PRINCESA CITY (CAPITAL)"

gsub("\\W*"," ",s)

"PUERTO PRINCESA CITY CAPITAL "
```

I'll illustrate my point using the data below:

**The point is that my when I copy the gsub on stackoverflow the character I want to remove disappears.**

And I don't know the name of the character. Let's pretend that there is a character "_" that \W will remove.

```
 df <-data.frame(col1= c("OCCIDENTAL_MINDORO", "ORIENTAL_MINDORO", "PALAWAN_*",     "PUERTO_PRINCESA_CITY_(CAPITAL)"))


temp2 <- gsub("\\W+"," ",as.matrix(df))

 temp2
     col1                                                 
[1,] " O C C I D E N T A L M I N D O R O "                
[2,] " O R I E N T A L M I N D O R O "                    
[3,] " P A L A W A N "                                    
[4,] " P U E R T O P R I N C E S A C I T Y C A P I T A L "
```

desired results:

```
temp2 <- gsub("\\W*"," ",as.matrix(df))
     col1                           
[1,] "OCCIDENTAL MINDORO"           
[2,] "ORIENTAL MINDORO"             
[3,] "PALAWAN "                     
[4,] "PUERTO PRINCESA CITY CAPITAL "
```

Comment: Something like `gsub("\\W+"," ",df$col1)`? You have different regex for the second `gsub`, why would you do that?

Comment: You also state that you would like to remove a single symbol (whitespace? underscore?), but the regex you use does something different. Is that intentional?

Comment: That's true. It's just that in the second gsub there might not be any character to replace. But I'll fix it if it's confusing. The the regex does the job I want in the first gsub. So I think it's fine.

Comment: Please check your code once again: `gsub("\\W*"," ",s)` inserts a lot of whitespaces, so the output is now incorrect.

Comment: What exactly you want remove? The punctuations? `_`? Your question is very unclear and your example makes it even less clear. Neither you provided a desired output

Comment: Yes my example is not reporducible. I'll be clearer.

Comment: In the first example, it seems like you need `gsub("\\)|\\(", "", "PUERTO PRINCESA CITY (CAPITAL)")` While in the second, something like `gsub("([[:punct:]])", "", df$col1)` maybe?

Comment: gsub("([[:punct:]])", "", df$col1) does the job thanks. @tonytonov, It turns out that  gsub("\\W+"," ",as.matrix(a)) does as well, but  gsub("\\W*"," ",as.matrix(a)).